# Android sdk architecture

Tags: android, architecture, sdk

I'm newbie in development and I have to develop android sdk. It's going to wrap network API and provide `OAuth 2.0` authentication functionality. Also web sockets for session ending  and push notifications will be included in sdk. I'm planning to use Facade design pattern:

```
    public interface SdkFacadeInterface {
        AuthenticateRequest authenticate(); // http request

        StartCallRequest starCall(); // http request with establishing websocket connection, push notification sending

        SelectGatewayRequest selectGateway(); //http request

        EndCall endCall(); // http request called after web sockets connection closes

        HistoryRequest getHistory(); // http request

        void setFirebaseToken(Context context, String firebaseToken);

        interface Builder {
            Builder setCliendId(String cliendId);

            Builder setClientSecret(String clientSecret);

            Builder enablePushNotifications(booleanenablePushNotifications);

            Session build();
        }
    }
```

After authentication I need to save refresh token and access tocken to the phone storage, I'am planning to use SharedPrefs for it. I have the following questions:

1. What architecture should I use? Is there some architectural patterns for sdks which I can use
2. Maybe you know some sdk on `github` which I can use as reference for my project.
3. Can I use retrofit for *http request* or I rather use `AsynTask` with `HttpUrlConnection` so my sdk will have as little external dependencies as possible
4. Sdk development is different from applications development, what should I take in consideration for developing sdk(all suggestions and ideas a welcomed)
5. How should I handle bad input from clients, should I throw exception or just write error to logs (Log.e(..))

Thanks in advance